# Rename "scalaz-zio" to "zio"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

ZIO has a life on its own now, and people want to search on this tag directly. Nobody calls it "scalaz-zio". This can be confirmed by looking up the questions asked with this tag.

Please rename the [scalaz-zio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scalaz-zio) tag to [zio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zio).

Comment: You should consider [updating the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/137416) for that tag. It looks like it's quite out of date, too, still referring to the old GitHub repository.